# How to improve auc of a classifier?

Tags: classification, auc

I have a data set with binary imbalanced class problem. Only 12% of the records belong to positive class. The auc of the original dataset for many classifiers were around 0.6 or less. So I applied minority class oversampling techniques and majority class under sampling techniques and re evaluated. But the classifer auc is not improving more than 0.63. Why is this? How can I fix this? I even checked if there are duplicate records with opposite classes, but none.

Following is the output

```
  a    b   <-- classified as
 4179 1502 |    a = no
  469  373 |    b = yes

Correct..69.78384179058715
Incorrect % = 30.216158209412846
AUC = 0.6360277685212323
```

Comment: In the absence of any additional information, better features, more data, better algorithm, boosting, ensemble models, stacking and better hyper-parameters are all options.

Comment: Caution when you say "how can I fix this". Always ponder over the possibility that your data simply isn't more informative than that. Perhaps there isn't anything to "fix" at all.

Comment: While the model may not have any more signal, the model is clearly biased toward class a (McNemar's test p-value ~ 10^-119).  There is no guarantee that they can improve accuracy (they may even reduce it), but they can try to reduce model bias.

Comment: You need to ask a better question to get good answers.  My post [how to ask a statistics question](http://www.statisticalanalysisconsulting.com/how-to-ask-a-statistics-question/) may help.

Comment: There's some helpful practical advice in this chapter: http://www.deeplearningbook.org/contents/guidelines.html

Comment: thank you all, now I am trying with hyper parameter tuning

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your confusion matrix, there does still seem to be a problem to be fixed as your errors are not symmetric.  The first thing to do is look at your learning curves to be sure you aren't over fitting.  Over sampling has a strong possibility to over fit with many machine learning algorithms.  Depending on the ML algorithm, over sampling can teach the method "class b looks exactly like this but class a can be lots of things".  Imaging as an extreme example, a Radial Basis Function SVM classifier with over sampled data.  That function could make gamma really, really high making it so that the features of your new data point have to be practically identical to be classified correctly.  Still, since there is over sampling and the same data may be in both your training and your test set for validation, the machine could still get perfect accuracy in validation, even though it won't generalize at all.

One possible alternative (depending on your classification technique) is to use class weights instead using sampling techniques.  Adding a greater penalty to misclassifying your under represented class can reduce bias without "over training" on the under-represented class samples.

Another option could be leaving the samples alone changing your optimization metric to something not strongly effected by class bias like AUC or the [Kappa statistic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cohen%27s_kappa).

Comment: OP says he's using AUC though.

Comment: OP says they are evaluating the final model using AUC, not that they are tuning the model using AUC.  Many classification models (as well as things like the `caret::train` in `R`) default to using accuracy to tune the model.